# Is this a parsing issue with advanced conditionals?

Tags: conditionals, parse-order, ifelse, advanced-conditionals

I have a header snippet that includes a "Made in USA" image on it. Well the client now wants the image removed on a couple product pages. I setup an advanced conditional to check for those pages using the third url segment. It worked if I kept the conditional simple, but as soon as I added an "OR" it stopped working. I thought it was probably a parse order issue, so I installed the Croxton If/Else plugin. Implemented that and I still have the same problem. Any ideas?

Doesn't Work...

```
{if segment_3!="product1" OR segment_3!="product2"}
<img src="/images/styles/madeinusa.png" class="madeinusa"/>
{/if}
```

Doesn't Work...

```
{exp:ifelse parse="inward"} 
{if segment_3!='product1' OR segment_3!='product2"}
<img src="/images/styles/madeinusa.png" class="madeinusa"/>
{/if}
{/exp:ifelse}
```

Doesn't Work...

```
{exp:ifelse parse="inward"} 
{if segment_3!="product1"}
<img src="/images/styles/madeinusa.png" class="madeinusa"/>
{if:elseif segment_3!="product2"}
<img src="/images/styles/madeinusa.png" class="madeinusa"/>
{/if}
{/exp:ifelse}
```

Works...

```
    {if segment_3!="product1"}
<img src="/images/styles/madeinusa.png" class="madeinusa"/>
{/if}
```

Comment: With negative conditionals, you should use `AND` not `OR`. I'd also add space before and after your conditional operators to prevent any potential parsing bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I saw you already find a solution, but I think you should know the reason your code wasn't working.

Your conditional will never work... Ooops! Please, forgive me. Your conditional will **always** work because `"product1" != "product2"`.

This code will always evaluate:

```
{if segment_3!="product1" OR segment_3!="product2"}
    <img src="/images/styles/madeinusa.png" class="madeinusa"/>
{/if}
```

For this code to work, you'll need an "AND", not an "OR". So:

```
{if segment_3!="product1" AND segment_3!="product2"}
    <img src="/images/styles/madeinusa.png" class="madeinusa"/>
{/if}
```

But it's really better to split this into two conditionals if your code prevents some module parsing.

Answer (score 1):

this ended up working...Not sure why the If:Else plugin wasn't working though.

```
{if segment_3!="product1"}
    {if segment_3!="product2"}
    <img src="/images/styles/madeinusa.png" class="madeinusa"/>
    {/if}
{/if}
```